# Redirect request to different tomcat server according to requested urls

Tags: tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

I have two different tomcat sever on two different machine.
One of them is front server has public IP(url: xyz.com).
I have to configure tomcat such that if user type xyz.com/dev then request goes to 1st server and when user access xyz.com/demo, it will redirect him to 2nd server internally.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Please read http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html, there is all about the tomcat connector.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to put a web server in front of both Tomcats and route to the specific apps with modjk.

Comment: Thanks stefan....I did like this and it is working now.For other guys who have the same issue     can take help from the link http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/03/virtual-host-apache-httpd-server-tomcat.html